# Different column oder in CSV file. CSV header column names as Hive table column names?

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I'm receiving same CSV's but with different column order. 
My external hive tables are defined in DDL scripts using the same names as CSV column names. But it seems, it does not map the data by the CSV column name and "reading" that CSV file. I thought there would be any possible way how to make it?

```
drop table db.table;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db.table(`id` string, `text` string, `command` string)
row format SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('separatorChar'=',', 'quoteChar'='"','escapeChar'='\\') 
stored as textfile 
location ' .....  '
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

It would help so much.

Comment: "Skip header" property name is explicit: Hive does not care about the header, it's just junk to be skipped. The table definition is _positional_.

Comment: If you have 2 different formats, you could use an ugly trick: create a partitioned table with schema 1 ; create a partition for that schema (part. name irrelevant) ; ALTER to schema 2 (but don't propagate to existing part) ; create another part with schema 2 on another dir. Then drop your files in the appropriate dir, depending on their actual schema. Yuck.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I know, it skips the header line. It is on purpose ;) But I tought if I use the same columne names as are in CSV, it would work.  I know Spark can work with CSV column names, but seems Hive cannot. And yes, that is really yacky solution. Its much more better to force the supplier to generate the same data each time, imho.